# jQuery autocomplete prevent focus after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Requirement:**

I'd like a jQuery autocomplete element that allows the user to pick an item and set the display field and a hidden field with the selected value. But I would also like the field and the hidden field to be cleared when the input field receives focus by the user.

**Problem:**

The problem I'm facing is that when the user selects an item it's almost like jQuery is executing the onSelect function and then sending the focus to the input field again which fires my focus() event (and therefore clearing my selection).

**Problem Browser:**

IE8 , works in Chrome. Did not try others.

**Attempted fixes:**

- I have tried setting the focus to another element in the `select()`
  function. It did put the focus on that element but only after
  focussing on the input field
- Tried both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` in the
  select() method. Did not work.
- Blur didnt work either.

**Workarounds:**

I guess I can change the clearing to be on click instead of on focus, but this is not what I want.

**Similar stackoverflow thread:**

[jquery autocomplete remove focus after suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834990/jquery-autocomplete-remove-focus-after-suggest)

**Code:**
Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#autosuggest").autocomplete({
        source: "my server path",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                $("#autosuggest").val(ui.item.value);                    
                $("#hidden").val(ui.item.id);                                                                                
            }
        }
    });
    $("#autosuggest").focus(function () {
        $("#hidden").val("");
        this.value = "";
    });

});
```

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870077/jquery-autocomplete-select-firing-after-change?rq=1?

Comment: @j08691 Thank for your reply, I'm nt sure that the suggested thread has the same problem as me, that post seems to deal with preventing the change event from firing, while I want the focus to pass to anything other than the input field after the user selects an item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: when you click on an autocomplete suggestion, the focus shifts to that dropdown menu, ever so shortly, to return to your input afterwards. Do you still get this problem if you choose the autocomplete suggestion by using the arrow-down button? If you do not, then this is the problem.

The only way I can see to fix this is not to make it a focus event after all, but I think I know why you don't want to make it a click event: you also want to capture tabbing into the field.

Solution: make it a click handler, and add a 'keyup' handler that executes the click handler handler if the key was a tab (arrow-down etc are still allowed).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're right, it does work when using the arrow keys. It works because when using the arrow keys, the focus never really leaves the input field, not even for a short while. This is because as Im using the arrow keys, I can still the cursor blinking on the input field. Further, even if it did leave focus for the briefest of moments, the very act of returning focus to the input field would fire the focus() method.

Comment: And yes, you're spot on with your reasons about why I dont want a simple click handler as  I would like to capture tabs and "next" buttons on phones.

Comment: Your solution will undoubtedly work,and thanks for the clever thinking. I will implement it now, but it does seem to be rather expensive as now the JS engine would have to execute 2 handlers for every key up, one for the "tab" listener and one for the jquery autosuggest list builder. oh well! I wish there was a simpler way to do it within the select() function. Thanks though for your time and thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this from the jQuery forum and it works fabulous!

```
select: function(event, ui) {
 $(event.target).autocomplete("close")
 setTimeout(function() {
  $(event.target).blur();
 })
}
```

Link: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-input-field-stays-focused-after-selection

Comment: works well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try onSelect function..

```
 $(function () {
    $("#autosuggest").autocomplete({
        source: "my server path",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                $("#autosuggest").val(ui.item.value);                    
                $("#hidden").val(ui.item.id);                                                                                
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        $(this).click();}
    });
    $("#autosuggest").focus(function () {
        $("#hidden").val("");
        this.value = "";
    });

});
```